# How could I change this php into ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

How could I change the following php into ajax?

```
<?php

    $selectMSGs = 'SELECT * FROM group_messages WHERE group_id="'.$_GET["id"].'" ORDER BY msg_id DESC';
    $selectMSGs2 = $connect->query($selectMSGs);
    while ($rowMSGs = $selectMSGs2->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<div class='lead MessageOfPerson'>";
        echo "<div class='NameOfPerson'>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $rowMSGs['msg_sender'];
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='MessageText'>";
        echo nl2br($rowMSGs['group_msg']);
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr>";

    }

?>
```

I already have some other ajax course (not my own) that is already being run on this page, could it be possible to combine this php together with my current ajax and php file? The files look like this:

ajax

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function updateChat(){

      $.ajax({

        //TODO set localhost to the strato livechat file
        url: "http://localhost:8080/LiveChat/LiveChat/code/php/groups/liveChat.php",
        type: "get",
        data: "msg_id="+$('#msg_id').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response, status, http){

          $.each(response, function(index, item){

            $('#msg_id').val(item.msg_id);

            //TODO update messages

          });
        },
        error: function(http, status, error){

          alert( 'Error updating chat, ' + error);

        }
      });

    }

    //auto update chat
    setInterval( updateChat, 2000 );

</script>
```

php

```
<?php

    // Lets fetch the value of msg_id
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    $msg_id = $data['msg_id'];

    // Connect to MySQL Server TODO change to strato
    $con = mysqli_connect( "localhost" , "root" , "" , "db2723249" );

    // If msg_sender and group_msg is available then
    // add it in table chats
    if(
        isset( $data['msg_sender'] ) &&
        isset( $data['group_msg'] )
    ) {

        $insert = "
            INSERT INTO group_messages (group_id, group_msg, msg_sender)
            VALUES( '".$data['msg_sender']."' , '".$data['group_msg']."' )
        ";
        $insert_result = mysqli_query( $con , $insert );
    }

    $select = "SELECT *
                FROM group_messages
                WHERE msg_id > '".$msg_id."'
            ";
    $result = mysqli_query( $con , $select );

    $arr = array();
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows( $result );

    if( $row_count > 0 ) {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
            array_push( $arr , $row );
        }
    }

    // Close the MySQL Connection
    mysqli_close( $con );

    // Return the response as JSON
    echo json_encode( $arr );

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, after working on this for about 20 hours, I finally found out how to do it (without help:)! I was able to merge the old and new ajax and php.

The new ajax became

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function updateChat(){

          $.ajax({

            //TODO set localhost to the strato livechat file
            url: "http://localhost:8080/LiveChat/USB/code/php/groups/liveChat.php",
            type: "get",
            data: "msg_id="+$('#msg_id').val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response, status, http){

              $.each(response, function(index, item){

                $("#ChatBox").html("<div class='lead MessageOfPerson'> <div class='NameOfPerson'> <p>" + item.msg_sender + "</p> </div> </div> <div class='MessageText'> <p>" + item.group_msg + "</p> </div> <hr/>" + $('#ChatBox').html());


            $('#msg_id').val(item.msg_id);

          });
        },
        error: function(http, status, error){

          alert( 'Error updating chat, ' + error);

        }
      });

    }

    //auto update chat
    setInterval( updateChat, 2000 );

</script>
```

The php became:

```
<?php

    // Lets fetch the value of msg_id
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    $msg_id = $data['msg_id'];

    // Connect to MySQL Server TODO change to strato
    $con = mysqli_connect( "localhost" , "root" , "" , "db2723249" );

    // If msg_sender and group_msg is available then
    // add it in table chats
    if(
        isset( $data['msg_sender'] ) &&
        isset( $data['group_msg'] )
    ) {

        $insert = "
            INSERT INTO group_messages (group_id, group_msg, msg_sender)
            VALUES( '".$data['msg_sender']."' , '".$data['group_msg']."' )
        ";
        $insert_result = mysqli_query( $con , $insert );
    }

        $select = "SELECT * FROM group_messages WHERE msg_id > '".$msg_id."' ";

    $result = mysqli_query( $con , $select );

    $arr = array();
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows( $result );

    if( $row_count > 0 ) {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
            array_push( $arr , $row );
        }
    }

    // Close the MySQL Connection
    mysqli_close( $con );

    // Return the response as JSON
    echo json_encode( $arr );

?>
```